# How to winsorize a tensorflow tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

During training, I generate a tensor which contains some outlier values.How to set these outlier values to a proper smaller value? 
I have tried batch normalization but does not help.

Comment: Do you want to set outlier values to a fixed value?

Comment: Yes, but how to do this? I can't use assign() because 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

Answer (score 1):

You can use tf.clip_by_value. Put this operation at desired place.